# How to update Intel microcode properly?

Tags: intel

I've installed `intel-microcode=2.20140913.1ubuntu2` but I'm still getting `2014-05-29` loaded according to

```
dmesg | head -n1
```

Do I have to use `iucode-tool`?

Comment: What's your processor? Are you sure there's a more recent file?

Comment: 2117U. `20140913` looks more recent than `2014-05-29`, isn't it?

Comment: Wrong assumption, check the comment on my answer. What Intel does is, they stick all microcode updates for all processors in a single file. This file, even the most recent one, does not contain a brand new microcode update for each and every processor. In the case of my Croe 2 Duo, the most most recent file is from 2010, even if the microcode package is just weeks old...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Manual method

#### How to verify if there's a new microcode update for your processor (Intel)

Go to the [Intel drivers download center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Linux*+Processor+Microcode+Data+File). Download the most recent microcode and then unpack the file, giving you a `microcode.dat` file.

1. make sure you have the package `iucode-tool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install iucode-tool
   ```
2. Create temp folder:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/micro
   ```
3. "Unpack" this `microcode.dat` file to a temporary location:

   ```
   iucode_tool -K/tmp/micro microcode.dat
   ```
4. You can now check if there's a more recent microcode file using:

   ```
   modprobe cpuid && iucode_tool -tb -lS /tmp/micro
   ```

   (or wherever you unpacked the microcodes to).

   On my old Core 2 Duo the output is like this:

   ```
   iucode_tool: system has processor(s) with signature 0x0001067a
   selected microcodes:
   001: sig 0x0001067a, pf mask 0xa0, 2010-09-28, rev 0x0a0b, size 8192
   002: sig 0x0001067a, pf mask 0x11, 2010-09-28, rev 0x0a0b, size 8192
   003: sig 0x0001067a, pf mask 0x44, 2010-09-28, rev 0x0a0b, size 8192
   ```
5. Compare this to the output of:

   ```
   dmesg | grep "updated"
   ```

   Sample output:

   ```
   [    1.056012] microcode: CPU0 updated to revision 0xa0b, date = 2010-09-28
   [    1.112010] microcode: CPU1 updated to revision 0xa0b, date = 2010-09-28
   ```

   This shows that my system already uses the most recent microcode.

### Method using a repository

Follow the instructions in [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode) (note that you do not need to install `synaptic`)

1. Install the following packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install microcode.ctl intel-microcode
   ```
2. Reboot your computer.
3. Now check whether the microcode has been loaded properly, with the following terminal command:

   ```
   dmesg | grep microcode
   ```

   If all is well you should see several reports about the applied microcode.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not about comparing versions but applying a new one. Doesn't `intel-microcode` package already contain the microcode that is suitable for use?

Comment: Your assumption that the release date of Intels microcode file automatically means that it contains a more recent microcode update four your processor is wrong. Use my answer to verify **if there's a more recent microcode for your processor in the intel file**.

Comment: When I run `iucode_tool -Kmicrocode.dat` I get `iucode_tool: No valid microcodes were loaded, nothing to do...`, but if I run `iucode_tool -K microcode.dat` then it works. Looks like it cares about the space.

Comment: On my Linux Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu16.04.xx) the shipped version is 2017-01-27. Inte ìl instead published the 2018-01-18. How could apply it?

Answer (score 8):

Here is Pool of microcodes released by intel
http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/intel-microcode/

download latest .deb package and install via

```
sudo dpkg -i intel-microcode_3.20191115.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

in My case it's intel-microcode_3.20191115.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb

P.S:
ubuntu 18.04 shipped with 3.20180807a.0ubuntu0.18.04.1
and maintained to the latest, so no longer has to manually install it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix link updated 

Answer (score 3):

While @Rajat had the way to do it, his link is outdated
You will be able to find the latest microcode here: http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/intel-microcode/?C=M;O=D

than after that, as root on your machine, do something like this:

```
wget http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/intel-microcode/intel-microcode_3.20191115.1ubuntu0.19.10.3_amd64.deb
dpkg -i intel-microcode_3.20191115.1ubuntu0.19.10.3_amd64.deb
reboot
```

Comment: I have installed this version but still my system says the installed version is dated 03-10-2019 (dd-mm-yyyy). did anything like this happened to you.