# Why don't Intel microcode updates work on my system?

Tags: microcode

I want to upgrade my system to mitigate Spectre and Meltdown exploits.

[The relevant Ubuntu page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown) states that I need to update microcodes: 
"From a guest and non-hypervisor bare-metal perspective, as of the Feb 21 kernel updates, as far as we are aware, the mitigations for Spectre and Meltdown on 64-bit amd64, ppc64el and s390x are feature-complete as long as all microcode, firmware and hypervisor updates underneath the system are done. ..."

I have `intel-microcode` and `iucode-tool` installed and updated, however running `dmesg | grep -i microcode` and `grep -i microcode /var/log/syslog*` return nothing which makes me think that either the cpu microcode doesn't get updated or something else is wrong.

Packages are up to date and there have been restarts since the last update.

operating system: Lubuntu 16.04

CPU: Intel N3700 (Braswell)

enabled software repos: main, universe

enabled updates: xenial-security

**Edit:**
The output of `grep name /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u` is
`model name : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3700  @ 1.60GHz`

My processor is not Skylake, nor Kaby lake.

In `/proc/cpuinfo` hyper-threading shows up as supported, but this Intel page says it is not supported:
https://ark.intel.com/products/87261/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3700-2M-Cache-up-to-2_40-GHz

**Edit 2:**
I ran `sudo update-initramfs -u` and rebooted. The outputs are still the same.

Output of `/usr/sbin/iucode_tool -tb -lS /lib/firmware/intel-ucode/*`:

```
/usr/sbin/iucode_tool: system has processor(s) with signature 0x000406c3
selected microcodes:
```

It seems that there is no updated microcode for my cpu, which is interesting since there was a selectable microcode in the `Additional Drivers` tab previously (late 2017); now, there isn't.

**Edit 3:**
Output of `apt list --installed | grep intel-microcode`:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

intel-microcode/xenial-security,now 3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

**Edit 4:**
Now I understand that there is no update for the cpu microcode, which means that the original problem is solved, and I will leave it as it is.

However, `dmesg` and `journalctl -b` should still output lines about microcode version, I believe.
I also noticed that these boot logs start at "5" instead of the tipical 1 or 0, and that there is a repeating error message which makes them truncated (`dmesg` says nothing about truncation, but `journalctl` says there are 371635 missed kernel messages, see below). I will ignore this for now.

```
March 19 06:36:40 NN systemd-journald[266]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/) is 8.0M, max 78.9M, 70.9M free.
March 19 06:36:40 NN systemd-journald[266]: Missed 371635 kernel messages
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: handle_bad_irq+0x0/0x230
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->irq_data.chip(): ffffffffbb172c40, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: chv_gpio_irqchip+0x0/0x120
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->action():           (null)
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel:    IRQ_NOPROBE set
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: irq 115, desc: ffff9b91f5df8200, depth: 1, count: 0, unhandled: 0
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->handle_irq():  ffffffffb9ee8f70, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: handle_bad_irq+0x0/0x230
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->irq_data.chip(): ffffffffbb172c40, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: chv_gpio_irqchip+0x0/0x120
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->action():           (null)
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel:    IRQ_NOPROBE set
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: irq 115, desc: ffff9b91f5df8200, depth: 1, count: 0, unhandled: 0
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->handle_irq():  ffffffffb9ee8f70, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: handle_bad_irq+0x0/0x230
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->irq_data.chip(): ffffffffbb172c40, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: chv_gpio_irqchip+0x0/0x120
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->action():           (null)
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel:    IRQ_NOPROBE set
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: irq 115, desc: ffff9b91f5df8200, depth: 1, count: 0, unhandled: 0
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->handle_irq():  ffffffffb9ee8f70, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: handle_bad_irq+0x0/0x230
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: ->irq_data.chip(): ffffffffbb172c40, 
March 19 06:36:40 NN kernel: chv_gpio_irqchip+0x0/0x120
```

Comment: Here are detailed instructions on checking microcode on debian systems - https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/06/msg00308.html . Post the output of those commands. Start by identifying your processor with `grep name /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u` and note "Some of the processors in these two lists are not affected because they
lack hyper-threading support.  Run the command below in a command line
shell (e.g. xterm), and it will output a message if hyper-threading is
supported/enabled:" 
  `grep -q '^flags.*[[:space:]]ht[[:space:]]' /proc/cpuinfo && 
 echo "Hyper-threading is supported"`

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Can you please run `sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo reboot` and check again after reboot.

Comment: Maybe there isn't a microcode for your cpu in ubuntu's package. run this to see `/usr/sbin/iucode_tool -tb -lS /lib/firmware/intel-ucode/*`

Comment: I edited the question. It seems that there is no microcode for my cpu, which is interesting since there was a selectable microcode in the `Additional Drivers` tab previously (late 2017); now, there isn't.

Comment: @MeltingPoint One other command to try: `journalctl -b | grep microcode`. My additional driver's tab also says "Unknown / Unknown" today where it used to have Intel Microcode option highlighted. Yet dmesg shows it being loaded.

Comment: In "late 2017" you possibly had micro code for your cpu based on attempted spectre/meltdown fixes. That code has been removed/, i.e. the bundle has been reverted to previous which has nothing needed for your cpu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on results of `/usr/sbin/iucode_tool -tb -lS /lib/firmware/intel-ucode/*` no microcode is being loaded for your cpu  because at the moment there is none. That doesn't mean that there won't be in the future. You can safely leave intel-microcode and iucode-tool installed, if there is an update containing microcode for your cpu's signature it will then be used.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu had released fixed kernal update against this exploit. The new kernal have required changes.

Reference:
[SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown | Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown)

I am in Ubuntu 16.04, Using Nouveau display driver. In my case, Intel-microcode got uninstalled after installing new kernel.

This update is released right after intel had released  bug fix for spectre bugs security vulnerability.

This should solve your problem.

If you got intel property driver replaced like in my place and still want intel-microcode property driver.

[Intel Releases Linux CPU Microcodes To fix Meltdown & Spectre Bugs | bleepingcomputer.com](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/intel-releases-linux-cpu-microcodes-to-fix-meltdown-and-spectre-bugs/)

Currently, the new drivers are not included in Ubuntu ppa. Users may have to download it manually from Intel website.

Warning: This may cause driver conflict or instability in your Ubuntu. You have to install it on your own risk.

[Download Linux Processor Microcode Data File | downloadcenter.intel.com](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27591?v=t)

For me, I have no issue in my ubuntu laptop. So I don't want to take risk.  I left Ubuntu team to decide what is best from my system. I am waiting update from Ubuntu driver team.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers to my question. Can you explain? I have `intel-microcode` installed.

Comment: Simple, https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/01/04/ubuntu-updates-for-the-meltdown-spectre-vulnerabilities

Comment: Update your kernal, Ubuntu had patched it in another way.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown

Comment: If intel-microcode got uninstalled, you have 2 option. option 1) stay safe and wait till ubuntu team release the update like I do. Or 2) you can run your own experiment by downloading manually in your own risk.

Comment: Sorry if my english is poor. I am little week in framing sentence.

Comment: Download center link is this https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27591?v=t

Comment: I hope you got it now. I hope you will read 2 last link to find out what type of fix will be  applied in your case. In my case fix is that i have to get intel property driver uninstalled. This is because I have Nouveau. It is Intel compatable.

Comment: Your Intel Microcode link is for March 12 2018 version which is Ubuntu proposed and Ubuntu 18.04 but not recommended for the average user. The Intel Microcode current version is: `3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1` released January 8 2018 as a bug fix to Intel's bumbled Meltdown/Spectre security hole patches.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix. I agree that link is not for average user. But the suggestion is applicable in 16.04 user. It got applied in my case. I am in 4.13 kernal for ubuntu16.04. Bumbled is for nvidia. Ubuntu have enhanced Nouveau. It is advisable that you run sudo apt update and install your kernal upgrade. Average use should stick with ubuntu tuning as you told. But advanced super user expected to do experiment with new kernal. Hence i suggested the link.

Answer (score 2):

## Bug in Meltdown/Spectre Intel Microcode

There was a [bug in early 2018 Intel Microcode update](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000454/307523) to address Meltdown/Spectre security holes. As such the microcode had to be rolled back to a previous version.

Here is the microcode I'm using (having opted out of all updates starting January 2018):

```
$ apt list --installed | grep intel-microcode

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

intel-microcode/now 3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1]
```

When you install Intel Microcode Update you will get this version or something similar:

```
intel-microcode/3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1
```

## Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Menu

I'm not sure about Lubuntu menu structure but for regular Ubuntu this is how you access the Intel Microcode Update controls:

[image: Additional Drivers.png]

The bottom option controls Intel Microcode Updates.

## Install Intel Microcode from CLI

To skip the GUI menus altogether you can install from command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install intel-microcode
```

## `dmesg` now shows correct output

After following the installation steps `dmesg` returns the desired output (unlike in your question where it shows nothing):

```
$ dmesg | grep -i microcode
[    1.166542] microcode: sig=0x506e3, pf=0x20, revision=0xba
[    1.166993] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
[16082.584598] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xba, date = 2017-04-09
```

Comment: In the question the OP clearly states "I have intel-microcode and iucode-tool installed and updated" so I am not really sure how this helps.

Comment: @Panther I missed adding my `dmesg` output I originally had when I started writing the answer. I'll add that in. Basically after following the installation steps the `dmesg` output appears as it is supposed to.

Comment: The OP also clearly states "running dmesg | grep -i microcode and grep -i microcode /var/log/syslog* return nothing" . I suspect we need to run `sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo reboot`

Comment: @Panther It first appeared to me that microcode wasn't installed correctly. Good point about rebooting. The OP mentions nothing about that. I'll monitor OP's future reply to your comment under his question. I'm not sure about `update-initramfs -u` being needed as it's not listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/545925/how-to-update-intel-microcode-properly. However it never hurts.

Comment: The microcode is normally part of the initramfs and is loaded during boot so, although not expected, I am suggesting rebuilding the initramfs as a possible fix to the OP unusual situation. Would help if we knew which microcode was installed.

Comment: @Panther agree 100% on knowing what microcode is installed. The first part of my answer illustrates using `apt list` to see what is installed.

Comment: @Panther upon rereading OP's question I see: ***"there have been restarts since the last update"***. I think `apt list` mentioned earlier will provide details and then if necessary `sudo apt install intel-microcode`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74723/discussion-between-panther-and-wineunuuchs2unix).