# Updated amd microcode do not load after reboot

Tags: 64-bit, amd-processor, microcode

After install of updated microcode "sudo apt install amd64-microcode" on ubuntu 16.04, after reboot microcode do not load. Its needed to patch spectre v2 and without it the computer is vulnerable.

[1.702088]microcode: CPU0: patch_level=0x07030105

[1.702099]microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x07030105

[1.702111]microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x07030105

[1.702121]microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x07030105

[1.702181]microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.

Comment: How did you determine that "after reboot microcode do not load"?

Comment: by doing "dmesg | grep microcode"

Comment: it show the same version off microcode that it had before update

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016971/why-dont-intel-microcode-updates-work-on-my-system/1017078

Comment: @Panther OP has AMD, not Intel.

Comment: @JoséAlmeida the `amd64-microcode` is from 2016, and probably doesn't contain the newer microcode that you're looking for. Visit the AMD site and check for newer microcode there. If it's there, you can probably use it with `amd64-microcode`.

Comment: Yes its there, i have it but i do not know how to install it ?

Comment: You'll probably have to `sudo cp` the newer microcode files into some subdirectory of `/lib/firmware/`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, it did not load either, but apt wanted to autoremove it - just to install it again afterwards (on apt-get update). Turns out an "apt-get dist-upgrade" was needed to upgrade the linux-generic. Afterwards, the amd-microcode was uptodate again (and the autoremove issue went away).